# How to specify we don't know the gender

Tags: word-usage, gender-neutral

I was talking about the short story "[The Invisible Japanese Gentlemen](http://archive.spectator.co.uk/article/7th-january-1966/9/short-story)" by Graham Greene. The narrator is part of the story and also talks about himself/herself. They ask me what we know about the narrator, so I thought I'd give as many details as possible.

> The narrator, who can’t **be deduced to be** a male or female, describes
>   them as (…)

Is it correct or awkward? How would you phrase this concept? ("A person who cannot be deduced to be male or female", and also more generally, the idea that "x cannot be deduced to be y or z.")

Comment: I don't understand the question, What is wrong with saying, "*The narrator describes them as (...)*"?  Why make a point of not knowing their gender--is it important in the context? If so, please state the context.

Comment: Is "to be deduced to be" correct?

Comment: "can't be deduced to be" sounds awkward to me.

Comment: The implication of the observation I pointed out is that you would, ordinarily, not need to point out the deduction: "the narrator, who might be male or female, ..."

Comment: Here I go. I was talking about the short story The Invisible Japanese Gentlemen by Graham Greene. The narrator is part of the story and also talks about himself/herself. They ask me what we know about the narrator, so I thought I'd give as many details as possible.

Comment: @sumelic The concept of "a person who cannot be deduced to be male or female", but consequently the other too. Sorry if it's confusing.

Comment: "The narrator, whose gender is left unspecified, ..."

Comment: Is this what you want:  "The narrator, in an *androgynous voice*, says ....."

Comment: Understand that wording will differ considerably depending on whether you're writing a story or simply writing commentary.  In the latter case it's perfectly fine to explicitly say we can't tell the gender.  In the former case you generally want to infer that information without explicitly saying it.

Comment: It's on hold because you took so long to get to the point and didn't ask a proper question.  Also this thing about deduction has nothing to do with the title.  Now that I know what the question is, I'll take pity and give you the answer. You ask, "How to specify we don't know the gender" and the answer is, "*The narrator, whose gender we don't know, describes them as (...)*"   Next time please ask us what you want to know. Don't  make something up and ask if it is right.

Comment: I know, sometimes it's hard to express oneself. It's like one doubt leads to another. I'm not really used to ask these kinds of questions. And yes, I think the question has been more than answered in the comments, but maybe it'd be more clear for others if there was at least an answer with all the possibilities. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Understood. If you think the question and answers might be useful to others, you could ask another question. I doubt this one will be reopened. Anyway, a more thorough answer pertaining to the awkwardness of the phrase "be deduced to be" is suggested by this Ngram: [**be deduced to be**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=be+deduced+to+be&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbe%20deduced%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0). Click links at bottom in the Ngram to see uses in context. Context will, finally, determine the awkwardness quotient.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more suited to Writing.SE.